# $setValidity inside validRegex directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive like this:

```
  .directive('validRegex', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
          console.log(viewValue);
          try {
            var regex = new RegExp(viewValue);
            ngModel.$setValidity('notRegex', true);
            return viewValue;
          } catch(e) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('notRegex', false);
            return undefined;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

and I use it like:

```
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input class="form-control" valid-regex id="search-text" type="text" ng-model="selectedSearchText"/>
    <span ng-show="selectedSearchText.$error.notRegex" class="form-error">
      Invalid Regular Expression
      <span class="icon-attention app_icon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>{{selectedSearchText}}</p>
```

If regex is invalid the the text don't show up as expected but no error message. I've search SO but didn't find a fix.

Comment: Please read (again) attentively [this section of the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose the input field with in a form as follows

```
<form name="form">

    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input class="form-control" valid-regex id="search-text" type="text" ng-model="selectedSearchText" name="selectedSearchText"/>
    <span ng-show="form.selectedSearchText.$error" class="form-error">
      Invalid Regular Expression
      <span class="icon-attention app_icon"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p>{{selectedSearchText}}</p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just found this in documention link @Blackhole give in a comment.